# How to increase worker nodes without restarting spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

The cluster manager will try to use yarn.

How to increase worker nodes without restarting spark cluster?

Comment: You want to add more executors to spark or do you want to add more instances into your cluster?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I want to add more instances to the cluster.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include more details regarding your cluster? Is it your custom cluster or is it some managed service like Amazon EMR?

Comment: That cluster is a custom cluster and I want to build using multiple EC2s.